# Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [1.1]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I changed versionCode from 1.0 to 1.1 like this:

```
versionCode 1.1
versionName "1.1"
```

And now I can't sync the project because it is giving me this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException:
>   Could not find method versionCode() for arguments [1.1] on
>   DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null,
>   minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=16, mCodename='null'},
>   targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=28, mCodename='null'},
>   renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null,
>   renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=1, versionName=1.10.1,
>   applicationId=com.github.fahadmaqsood.likhat, testApplicationId=null,
>   testInstrumentationRunner=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner,
>   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null,
>   testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
>   mBuildConfigFields={CRASH_REPORT_EMAIL_ADDRESS=com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl@b2244504},
>   mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
>   mManifestPlaceholders={}, mWearAppUnbundled=null} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DefaultConfig.

Comment: version code cannot be 1.1. It should always be an int

Comment: So I should change versionCode to 2?

Comment: Yes you should increment it by 1

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) for more info

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi thanks, it worked!

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi you can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning), the version code must be a positive integer.

It is usually incremented by 1 every time there is an update.

Answer (score 3):

**You cannot add a Float value as the VersionCode. Because, the version code accepts only positive Integer digits as a valid Version code.**

**As per the official documentation:**

> versionCode — A positive integer used as an internal version number.
>   This number is used only to determine whether one version is more
>   recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent
>   versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number
>   is set by the versionName setting, below. The Android system uses the
>   versionCode value to protect against downgrades by preventing users
>   from installing an APK with a lower versionCode than the version
>   currently installed on their device.
>
> The value is a positive integer so that other apps can
>   programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or
>   downgrade relationship. You can set the value to any positive integer
>   you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of
>   your app uses a greater value. You cannot upload an APK to the Play
>   Store with a versionCode you have already used for a previous version.

[Official Documentation Version Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)